# App Service deployment failure with VSTS release hub

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a very basic VSTS Release Management setup that is failing. I keep getting the following error message:

App Service '(name of app service)' doesn't exist. App Service should exist before deployment. The "Azure Subscription" is an Azure Service Connection, because when selecting the subscription, it wouldn't let me save.

The app service definitely exists. See the screenshot for my setup details.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the app service exists within the subscription you've selected and that the app service isn't restricted by RBAC to only certain users?

Comment: @DanielMann We only have one subscription, so I'm positive it is. Regarding RBAC, we are restricting to certain users. How do I give RBAC access to VSTS?

Comment: Did you set that up from Azure Portal or VSTS Portal? If Azure Portal, did you choose 'Deployment options' or 'Continuous Delivery (Preview)'?

Comment: @TylerFindlay VSTS creates a service principal in your directory that it uses to deploy.  We automatically add it as a contributor on the subscription when you authorize the connection.  You should check that it has access to that app service.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I did setup Deployment Options and made sure it was connected. I didn't use Continuous Deployment (Preview)

Comment: @TylerFindlay if you did Deployment Options, you should not have anything under Build/Releases in VSTS. Anyway, see my answer, which was probably your problem.

Comment: @TylerFindlay What's the result now?

Comment: What's the result if you create a new app service, then deploy to this app service through VSTS build/release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a VSTS issue that just got resolved, and could have contributed to your problem. The issue has now been resolved. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/603fc9c5-e211-490d-a375-aefc73c57bbb/solved-jamal-hartnett-pushed-updates-to-fabrikamfibergitmaster-what-does-that-mean?forum=TFService for details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed mine. Just reran the build and got the same issue. Thanks for suggesting it though!

Comment: What do you mean by 'reran the build'? Do you mean from Azure Portal or VSTS? There should be no build at all in VSTS based on how you are set up. Just try pushing a change to your git repo on VSTS, and that should trigger a deployment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant reran the release in VSTS. It is the release script that gave me the error as seen in the screenshot

Comment: Again, you should not have any release script in VSTS based on the way you are set up. All you should have in a Service Hook, which you can see by clicking on Tools (little wheel) / Service Hooks. Did you try just pushing to your repo and checking if it gets deployed to Azure?

Comment: I checked your app, and it was successfully deployed at 20:40 UTC. You should see this in the Azure Portal under deployments. Earlier today, this would not have worked due to this issue VSTS was having.

Comment: That was a manual publish. I've gotten it working since though just using Azure's VSTS "Continuous Deployment" template. My guess is there is some permission I missed setting that gets done automagicallly with the VSTS template.